# External monitor connected to DisplayLink docking looses connection sporadically

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, displaylink

I currently have a Dell Latitude 5490 with an external monitor connected to a DisplayLink docking station, running Ubuntu 19.10. As the title says, the external monitor will shut off sporadically.

Everything can function normally for hours, and then without any forewarning the connection to the external monitor is seemingly lost. It's not clear to me what triggers it, it can happen while I'm currently working on something and the computer is in active use.

When it happens the speakers connected to the docking station usually make a short crackling noise, but I haven't registered that any other devices connected to the docking (keyboard, speakers) are disconnected.

To get the monitor working again, I usually proceed to disconnect the docking station by pulling the USB-plug and then reconnect it again. Any advice on what may be causing this issue and how to solve it is most welcome.

Comment: I have this problem too. Did you ever get to the bottom of it?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have not found a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [External monitor screen freezes and Bluetooth stops working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257315/external-monitor-screen-freezes-and-bluetooth-stops-working)